# Using Solr to store user specified information in documents

Tags: solr, lucene, indexing, commit

I have an application that contains a set of text documents that users can search for. Every user must be able to search based on the text of the documents. What is more, users must be able to define custom tags and associate them to a document. Those tags are used in two ways:

1)Users must be able to search for documents based on specific tag ids.
2)There must be facets available for the tags.

My solution was adding a Mutivalued field in each document to pose as an array that contains the tagids that this document has been tagged with. So far so good. I was able to perform queries based on text and tagids ( for example text:hi AND tagIds:56 ).

My question is, would that solution work in production mode in an environment that users add but also remove tags from the documents ? Remember , I have to have the data available in real time, so whenever a user removes/adds a tag I have to reindex that document and commit immediately. If that's not a good solution, what would be an alternative ?

Answer (score 0):

[Stackoverflow uses Solr](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/stack-overflow-search-now-81-less-crappy/) - this is in case if you doubt Solr abilities in production mode.

And although I couldn't find much information on how they have implemented tags, I don't think your approach sounds wrong. Yes, tagged documents will have to be reindexed (that means a slight delay) but other than that I don't see anything wrong with it.